# How to make Keyboard application in android

Tags: android, keyboard, key

I want to make keyboard Application in android.

for That, I try below code, But it does't work.

1. I make button1 in activity,
2. I press button1
3. then i want it works same as when i press enter key in keyboard.

How can I do this? Please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button1;
EditText edit;

KeyEvent keyevent1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){

            keyevent1 = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);


            System.out.println("aaaa:  " + keyevent1);

            onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER, keyevent1);

        }

    });     
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    System.out.println("bbbb:  " + event);

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

Comment: in Android sdk there is sample is avaliable so please check sample and do something on it

Comment: I checked Android sdk, but I don't know what am i wrong. please help..^^

Comment: D:\Android\Android-Sdk\android-sdk\samples\android-16\SoftKeyboard have a look this one on your sdk

Answer (score 0):

```
addCourseText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clEtAddCourse);
addCourseText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                addCourseFromTextBox();
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}});
```